# Xcode 13 application projects open as text instead of project settings editor

Tags: xcode, editor, target, project-settings

After upgrading from Xcode 12 to 13, when I open an Xcode workspace with multiple application projects and click/select a project in the Navigator view, Xcode opens the project as a text file instead of the projects settings view (the one with multiple tabs and target definitions).

By the way, similar problem happens when I select a .plist file within the Navigator - it opens up as xml text file instead of the Property List Editor spreadsheet-like view.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Updated answer:

Menu Bar: View > Hide Code Review

Original answer:

> I haven't found any other workaround than:
>
> 1. committing changes
> 2. removing repo
> 3. cloning it again
>
> Then I was able to checkout the branch and continue in work.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer as it is a workaround. Actually, the "code review" button as mentioned in the answer below from @Artemiy is the right solution.

Comment: You're right. I have updated my answer

Comment: Menu Bar: View > Hide Code Review is working Thanks

Answer (score 25):

I had this issue and found a button which switches the mode:

[image]