how to show the general of project in Xcode?
how to show the project of general view in xcode 16.2
in Xcode version 14.2, the General window show as below

but in Xcode version 16.2, that's seems something wrong?

could anyone help me how to solve this problem?
i want to get the correct the general windwo in xcode version 16.2

Right click on the project in navigator and select « Xcode project » ?

Menu Bar: View > Hide Code Review Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70062537/xcode-13-application-projects-open-as-text-instead-of-project-settings-editor

@Vivek Patel thanks you a lot , it's work

it's work
Menu Bar: View > Hide Code Review Reference
